# Gimp python-fu , open a directory selection dialog

Tags: python-2.7, gimp

I want the user of a script to be able to select a directory to do "stuff". Not open a JPG or save a XCF. I just need a directory, because my script will do stuff including reading multiple files, and save multiple transformations.

I am supposed to be able to use

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

But gimp 2.10.24 has a... custom... install of the end-of-life python 2.7, and I get the error
`This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.`

So is there something like "pdb.open_directory" built into gimp? What about other python libraries shipped with gimp, but actually work? I'd also be satisfied if I could get Tkinter working in gimp, but that seems even harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the auto-generated parameter dialog for your Python-fu, then it's just a matter of using a parameter with a PF_DIRNAME type. For instance

```
register(
    'export-tiles',
    "Export tiles","Export tiles",author,author,year,"Export tiles...",
    '*',
    [
        (PF_IMAGE,      'image',        'Input image', None),
        (PF_DIRNAME,    'directory',    'Directory',   '.'),
        (PF_STRING,     'namePattern',  'Tile name',   '{imageName}-{column1:02d}-{row1:02d}.png'),
        (PF_SPINNER,    'rows',         'Rows',        10, (1,1000,1)),
        (PF_SPINNER,    'columns',      'Columns',     10, (1,1000,1))
    ],
    [],
    exportTiles,
    menu="<Image>/File/"
)
```

will elicit a dialog like this:

[image]

where the `Directory` button opens a directory selector and the function defined as:

```
def exportTiles(image,directory,namePattern,rows,columns):
```

will automatically receive a `gimp.Image` object in `image` (the active image when you call the script), a directory as a python string (`'/tmp'`) in `directory`, the name pattern (as a python string) in `namePattern`, and rows and columns as python floats.

Comment: Thanks xenoid! Future readers, note that you must re-define your function to take the string parameters described in the array of tupples used as an argument in the call to "register". Also note that now when you test from the console, you must provide a directory string argument, and calls from the console do not open GUI dialogs.

Comment: Of course the declaration of arguments in `register()`must match the function arguments. If you test from the console your main problem is to get a reference to the image. If you have only one image load in Gimp you can use `gimp.image_list()[0]`. Otherwise you can filter the list to find the image where the ID attribute is the one in the title bad (the X.Y number is the Image.ID and the image.Display index).

Comment: If you are on Linux, you can debug your plugin easily: 1) create the registration code and the function skeleton, 2) start Gimp 3) Execute the plugin, the output of any `print` statement will show up in the terminal, you just need to edit/save for the next attempt, restarting Gimp is necessary only if you change the registration data.